# How to connect fancy box id with div containing the description?

Tags: php, fancybox

What i'm trying to achieve here is to have the fancybox open a module with an image/title/description.

The only trouble i've had so far is that the data either goes the same for every member i'm trying to add or doesn't show at all.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'thegem_team_person', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category' => 'current' ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                **<a class="fancybox" href="#link">**<img src="<?php echo $picturedy;?>">
                    <h3 style="padding-top: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: #333;"><?php the_title();?></h3>
                    <p style="color: #11a9d4; padding-bottom: 10px; text-decoration: none;"> <?php the_title();?> </p></a>
                 <div id="#link"> 
                     
                     <h3 style="padding-top: 20px; text-decoration: none; color: #333;"><?php the_title();?></h3>
                    <?php $dscp = get_field('description');
                  echo $dscp;?> 
                 
                 </div>
                
     
              </div>                    
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

What i'm trying to do here is that when you click on the `<a class="fancybox" href="#"></a>`
the div with #link id to pop up. I have only had the chance to do it in html. Where i had to register every person one by one.

I hope i was clear, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: It depends on the version you are using. Look for docs, there are samples for cases like this.

Comment: Dear,

I'm not really sure, what do you mean with version (i don't want to sound rude, not my intention). 
Can you please find the time and send me a sample case? 
Thank you

Comment: Fancybox currently has 4 major versions that are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i have found, in case anybody else needs it in the future.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
'post_type' => 'name_of_the_custom_post_type',  
'posts_per_page' => -1, 
'category' => 'current' ) ); 
?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
  <a class="fancybox" href="#team<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
     <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
    <p> <?php the_title();?> </p>
  </a>
  <div> 
<div id="team<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
<h3 class="fancy-box-title"><?php the_title();?></h3>
<p><?php $dscp = get_field('description');
     echo $dscp;?> </p>
     </div>
        </div>
            </div>      
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The part get_field('description') is a field i've created with Advanced Custom Fields.